# Fresh install, Civicrm Wordpress, bricks admin

Tags: wordpress, install

I'm having trouble installing CiviCRM.  I can activate the plugin, enter the database credentials (tested via command line, and the app does connect and create the tables and what not).  I hit the install button, and it does some work, then shows me a type of confirmation screen for a few seconds, but then redirects to

/wp-admin/options-general.php?page=civicrm-install

And in the browser says: "The site is experiencing technical difficulties. Please check your site admin email inbox for instructions."

The error stack trace at bottom of this post.  Snippets here:

Looks like the fatal error is "Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function set_current_screen()"

but the cause underlying it is more related to  #4 /opt/bitnami/apps/wordpress/htdocs/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/packages/DB.php(984): PEAR_Error->__construct('DB Error: synta...', -2, 16, Array, '\nSELECT  v.labe...')\n

which is at a higher level run by

`CiviCRM_For_WordPress->initialize()\n
CiviCRM_For_WordPress->register_hooks_clean_urls()\n
CiviCRM_For_WordPress->register_hooks_common()\n`

And, I see the browser error on any wp-admin page I go to.  So it kinda bricks the whole admin.

When I go to the public facing wordpress homepage, I get simpler error in the error log:

AH01071: Got error 'PHP message: PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught CRM_Core_Exception: [0: Transaction integrity error: Expected to find active frame\n\n  thrown in /opt/bitnami/apps/wordpress/htdocs/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/Civi/Core/Transaction/Manager.php on line 107'

I can reset the world by dropping the civicrm specific database, creating an empty database in its place, and deleting the wp-content/uploads/civicrm folder.  That lets me get back into the wordpress admin.

`Apache2: Server version: Apache/2.4.39 (Unix)
php-fpm: PHP 7.3.5
mysql: Ver 8.0.16
wordpress: 5.2.1
os: ubuntu
civicrm: civicrm-5.13.4`

`Got error 'PHP message: PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function set_current_screen() in /opt/bitnami/apps/wordpress/htdocs/wp-admin/admin-header.php:31
 \nStack trace:\n
 #0 /opt/bitnami/apps/wordpress/htdocs/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Utils/System/Base.php(269): require_once()\n
 #1 /opt/bitnami/apps/wordpress/htdocs/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Utils/System.php(218): CRM_Utils_System_Base->theme('__construct('DB Error: synta...', -2, 16, Array, '\\nSELECT  v.labe...')\n
 #5 /opt/bitnami/apps/wordpress/htdocs/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/vendor/pear/pear-core-minimal/src/PEAR.php(575): DB_Error->__construct(-2, 16, Array, '\nSELECT  v.labe...')\n
 #6 /opt/bitnami/apps/wordpress/htdocs/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/vendor/pear/pear-core-minimal/src/PEAR.php(223): PEAR->_raiseError(Object(DB_mysqli), NULL, -2, 16, Array, '\nSELECT  v.labe...', 'DB_Error', true)\n
 #7 /opt/bitnami/apps/wordpress/htdocs/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/packages/DB/common.php(1907): PEAR->__call('raiseError', Array)\n
 #8 /opt/bitnami/apps/wordpress/htdocs/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/packages/DB/mysqli.php(933): DB_common->raiseError(-2, NULL, NULL, '\nSELECT  v.labe...', '1064 ** You hav...')\n
 #9 /opt/bitnami/apps/wordpress/htdocs/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/packages/DB/mysqli.php(403): DB_mysqli->mysqliRaiseError()\n
 #10 /opt/bitnami/apps/wordpress/htdocs/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/packages/DB/common.php(1216): DB_mysqli->simpleQuery('\nSELECT  v.labe...')\n
 #11 /opt/bitnami/apps/wordpress/htdocs/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/packages/DB/DataObject.php(2415): DB_common->query('\nSELECT  v.labe...')\n
 #12 /opt/bitnami/apps/wordpress/htdocs/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/packages/DB/DataObject.php(1607): DB_DataObject->_query('\nSELECT  v.labe...')\n
 #13 /opt/bitnami/apps/wordpress/htdocs/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Core/DAO.php(439): DB_DataObject->query('\nSELECT  v.labe...')\n
 #14 /opt/bitnami/apps/wordpress/htdocs/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Core/DAO.php(1414): CRM_Core_DAO->query('\nSELECT  v.labe...', true)\n
 #15 /opt/bitnami/apps/wordpress/htdocs/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Core/OptionGroup.php(169): CRM_Core_DAO::executeQuery('\nSELECT  v.labe...', Array)\n
 #16 /opt/bitnami/apps/wordpress/htdocs/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Core/PseudoConstant.php(291): CRM_Core_OptionGroup::values('languages', false, false, false, NULL, 'label', true, false, 'name', 'weight')\n
 #17 /opt/bitnami/apps/wordpress/htdocs/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Contact/BAO/Contact.php(3513): CRM_Core_PseudoConstant::get('CRM_Contact_BAO...', 'preferred_langu...', Array, NULL)\n
 #18 /opt/bitnami/apps/wordpress/htdocs/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Core/I18n.php(195): CRM_Contact_BAO_Contact::buildOptions('preferred_langu...')\n
 #19 /opt/bitnami/apps/wordpress/htdocs/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Core/I18n.php(266): CRM_Core_I18n::languages()\n
 #20 /opt/bitnami/apps/wordpress/htdocs/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Core/Smarty.php(154): CRM_Core_I18n::uiLanguages()\n
 #21 /opt/bitnami/apps/wordpress/htdocs/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Core/Smarty.php(172): CRM_Core_Smarty->initialize()\n
 #22 /opt/bitnami/apps/wordpress/htdocs/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Core/Error.php(188): CRM_Core_Smarty::singleton()\n
 #23 /opt/bitnami/apps/wordpress/htdocs/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/vendor/pear/pear-core-minimal/src/PEAR.php(922): CRM_Core_Error::handle(Object(DB_Error))\n
 #24 /opt/bitnami/apps/wordpress/htdocs/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/packages/DB.php(984): PEAR_Error->__construct('DB Error: synta...', -2, 16, Array, '\nSELECT  v.valu...')\n
 #25 /opt/bitnami/apps/wordpress/htdocs/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/vendor/pear/pear-core-minimal/src/PEAR.php(575): DB_Error->__construct(-2, 16, Array, '\nSELECT  v.valu...')\n
 #26 /opt/bitnami/apps/wordpress/htdocs/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/vendor/pear/pear-core-minimal/src/PEAR.php(223): PEAR->_raiseError(Object(DB_mysqli), NULL, -2, 16, Array, '\nSELECT  v.valu...', 'DB_Error', true)\n
 #27 /opt/bitnami/apps/wordpress/htdocs/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/packages/DB/common.php(1907): PEAR->__call('raiseError', Array)\n
 #28 /opt/bitnami/apps/wordpress/htdocs/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/packages/DB/mysqli.php(933): DB_common->raiseError(-2, NULL, NULL, '\nSELECT  v.valu...', '1064 ** You hav...')\n
 #29 /opt/bitnami/apps/wordpress/htdocs/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/packages/DB/mysqli.php(403): DB_mysqli->mysqliRaiseError()\n
 #30 /opt/bitnami/apps/wordpress/htdocs/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/packages/DB/common.php(1216): DB_mysqli->simpleQuery('\nSELECT  v.valu...')\n
 #31 /opt/bitnami/apps/wordpress/htdocs/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/packages/DB/DataObject.php(2415): DB_common->query('\nSELECT  v.valu...')\n
 #32 /opt/bitnami/apps/wordpress/htdocs/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/packages/DB/DataObject.php(1607): DB_DataObject->_query('\nSELECT  v.valu...')\n
 #33 /opt/bitnami/apps/wordpress/htdocs/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Core/DAO.php(439): DB_DataObject->query('\nSELECT  v.valu...')\n
 #34 /opt/bitnami/apps/wordpress/htdocs/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Core/DAO.php(1414): CRM_Core_DAO->query('\nSELECT  v.valu...', true)\n
 #35 /opt/bitnami/apps/wordpress/htdocs/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Core/OptionGroup.php(169): CRM_Core_DAO::executeQuery('\nSELECT  v.valu...', Array)\n
 #36 /opt/bitnami/apps/wordpress/htdocs/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Contact/BAO/Contact/Utils.php(1107): CRM_Core_OptionGroup::values('addressee', NULL, NULL, NULL, ' AND is_default...', 'value')\n
 #37 /opt/bitnami/apps/wordpress/htdocs/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Contact/BAO/Contact.php(480): CRM_Contact_BAO_Contact_Utils::defaultGreeting('Individual', 'addressee')\n
 #38 /opt/bitnami/apps/wordpress/htdocs/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Contact/BAO/Contact.php(286): CRM_Contact_BAO_Contact::ensureGreetingParamsAreSet(Array)\n
 #39 /opt/bitnami/apps/wordpress/htdocs/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Contact/BAO/Contact.php(2007): CRM_Contact_BAO_Contact::create(Array)\n
 #40 /opt/bitnami/apps/wordpress/htdocs/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Core/BAO/UFMatch.php(299): CRM_Contact_BAO_Contact::createProfileContact(Array, Array)\n
 #41 /opt/bitnami/apps/wordpress/htdocs/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Core/BAO/UFMatch.php(119): CRM_Core_BAO_UFMatch::synchronizeUFMatch(Object(WP_User), 1, 'user@example.co...', 'WordPress', NULL, 'Individual', false)\n
 #42 /opt/bitnami/apps/wordpress/htdocs/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm.php(915): CRM_Core_BAO_UFMatch::synchronize(Object(WP_User), false, 'WordPress', 'Individual')\n
 #43 /opt/bitnami/apps/wordpress/htdocs/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm.php(632): CiviCRM_For_WordPress->initialize()\n
 #44 /opt/bitnami/apps/wordpress/htdocs/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm.php(614): CiviCRM_For_WordPress->register_hooks_clean_urls()\n
 #45 /opt/bitnami/apps/wordpress/htdocs/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm.php(520): CiviCRM_For_WordPress->register_hooks_common()\n
 #46 /opt/bitnami/apps/wordpress/htdocs/wp-includes/class-wp-hook.php(286): CiviCRM_For_WordPress->register_hooks('')\n
 #47 /opt/bitnami/apps/wordpress/htdocs/wp-includes/class-wp-hook.php(310): WP_Hook->apply_filters(NULL, Array)\n
 #48 /opt/bitnami/apps/wordpress/htdocs/wp-includes/plugin.php(465): WP_Hook->do_action(Array)\n
 #49 /opt/bitnami/apps/wordpress/htdocs/wp-settings.php(525): do_action('init')\n#50 /opt/bitnami/apps/wordpress/htdocs/wp`

Comment: I also have this error with 5.17.4 on windows WAMP, with latest wordpress multisite.  Did you manage to resolve it? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Neither PHP 7.3 nor MySQL 8.0 are currently supported.  Looking at [system requirements](https://docs.civicrm.org/sysadmin/en/latest/requirements/) I see a minimum but not maximum version of MySQL; that needs correcting.  PHP 7.3 generally works but it's not part of the automated testing matrix as of now.

Comment: this error also occurs with PHP7.2.   I have the same problem with Wordpress 5.1.1 (or 5.2.1) PHP7.2 (Debian 9 Apache2) and MySQL 8.0.11.  The database is also correctly initialised.  I will try with a lower version of MySQL and report back.
p.s. I tried with both CiviCRM 5.14 and 5.16-alpha1

Answer (score 2):

I also see this error, using WP 5.2.2/MySQL 5.6 (recommended)/PHP 7.2 (recommended)/Apache 2.4/ on Windows 10, going back to Civicrm 5.5 (5.05) where updates to the Option Groups Admin UI were made(https://github.com/civicrm/civicrm-core/blob/5.5/release-notes/5.5.0.md) In the stack trace above you see refs to option group language members.
  Civicrm 5.40 does not have this problem.
  As noted above, if you comment-out/remove Civicrm DSN in civicrm_settings, you can get back into WP admin to disable Civi plugin.
 On Windows 7 with MySQL 5.5 this error does not show up, I can install Civicrm 5.15 no problem.